# Laravel mix vuejs router history mode

Tags: vuejs2, laravel-mix

I am using laravel mix and vuejs for my app and everything works fine.

Now I tried to change the VueRouter to history mode:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history'
})
```

On the ngix server, I added the catch all rule:

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

Because of that its still working, when accessing or refreshing top level urls like "/pages" or "/contact".

The only problem is with sublevel urls like `/pages/1` or `/foo/bar/boo`. Clicking on a router link still works, but if I try to refresh the page on `/pages/1` or if I try to directly access it (enter `/pages/1` in browser) its not working, since the browser tries to access the assets from `/pages/js/2.js` instead of `/js/2.js`

Comment: Remove the `/` from `/index.html` in your nginx configuration.

Comment: How should that help (it doesn't, I tried it out, just to be sure)? The ngix is working as expected, just the client side urls are wrong

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I just found it out - I had to set the public path to an absolute path in my webpack.mix.js file:

```
mix.webpackConfig({
    ...
    output: {
        ...
        publicPath: "/"
    }
});
```

Comment: it do not resolve my problem, still looking in **/pages/js/2.js** instead of **/js/2.js**

Comment: Maybe you can post your webpack.mix.js and your routes.js

Comment: My main problem is about *images* and *documents* in my vue projet, with history mode, when my Url is like [http://example.com/about] images are looking in [http://example.com/about/images/profil.jpg] instead of [http://example.com/images/profil.jpg]

Comment: here is my webpack.mix.js                                                                                                       `let mix = require('laravel-mix');                                                                                          
 mix.webpackConfig({
     output: {
         publicPath: '/'
  }
 });

mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');`

Comment: Hm. Maybe `mix.setPublicPath('public')` helps you?

Comment: thank for your answer, I have tried it, but it dosn't work!